# Парсинг xml с помощью Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

Необходимо реализовать парсинг xml с помощью Automapper версии 11. По аналогии как сделано тут:  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/706992/Using-AutoMapper-with-Complex-XML-Data С тех пор как был сделан пример, версия используется уже другая. Класс XAttributeResolver реализовала. Но не могу понять как делать сам вызов. Пробую так, но не получается:

````
```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<XElement, MenuItem>()
                  .ForMember(dest => dest.Name,
                             opt => opt.MapFrom < new XAttributeResolver<MenuItem, string>("name"));
```
````

Comment: AutoMapper - зло. Любая библиотека, добавленная в проект, должна упрощать и облегчать разработку. Меж тем автомаппер её усложняет. Англоязычный stackoverflow забит вопросами по автомапперу, на большинство из которых нет ответов. В статье [The reasons behind why I don't use AutoMapper](https://cezarypiatek.github.io/post/why-i-dont-use-automapper/) описана часть причин (далеко не все!), по которым эта утилита должна быть забыта. При чём в [ответной статье](https://jimmybogard.com/automapper-usage-guidelines/) сам автор автомаппера признаёт: DO NOT use AutoMapper.

Comment: Мда, идея лида была сразу парсить xml и натягивать на конечный класс, чтобы не делать два раза мэппинг по сути. Похоже странного хотел.

Comment: Идея нормальная, но она отродясь делалась с помощью (де)сериализации. [XML serialization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization). [XmlSerializer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=net-6.0).

Comment: А по поводу AutoMapper. Это моё личное мнение, что он бесполезен и не нужен. Большинство тянут десятки либ в проект и героически воюют с конфигами их настроек. "Зато кода много! Я погромист!"

Comment: С помощью  (де)сериализации можно xml сразу распарсить на класс отличный по структуре от xml?

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос (создайте новую тему), где покажите пример xml и код класса(ов) C#, в которые нужно распарсить.